# No overload for method FrameworkElement.FindName takes 1 argument

Tags: c#, .net, frameworkelement, findname

So I've got some code:

```
var columnHeader = (e.OriginalSource as GridViewColumnHeader);   
var temp = columnHeader.Template.FindName("Up");
```

When I click my GridViewColumnHeader I run this code. But the line `columnHeader.Template.FindName("Up")` is raising the error:
`No overload for method 'FindName' takes 1 arguments`

But what makes this different from any other question is the Microsoft documentation for [FrameworkElement.FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly shows a method that takes one argument:

> public Object FindName(   string name )
>
> Parameters name Type:
> System.String
>
> The name of the requested element.
>
> Return Value Type:
> System.Object
>
> The requested element. This can be null if no matching
> element was found.

So why does my compiler raise this error?

Comment: I don't think you are calling that method, you are calling this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GridViewColumnHeader.Template` is a [`ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate(v=vs.110).aspx), which inherits from `FrameworkTemplate`, not `FrameworkElement`:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate.findname(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public Object FindName(
    string name,
    FrameworkElement templatedParent
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Template has the type [ControlTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which inherits [FrameworkTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworktemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The latter takes two parameters, not one.